# Check if received param is equal of name from objects and get a random value of properties from these objects

Tags: javascript, random, javascript-objects, interaction

Check if received param is equal of name from objects and get a random value of properties from these objects.

Hi guys, i have one string and one object of objects like this:

```
var reveivedValue = '11:00:00',
var randomItem = '',
myObject = {
  '11:00:00': [ '1', '2', '3' ,'4'],
  '12:00:00': [ '5', '6', '7'],
  '13:00:00': [ '8' , '9' , '10' ]
}
```

**And I need received in "randomItem" one random value of array where the name of object of "myObject" === "receivedValue".**

I don't know how to make this interaction in objects, i just know how get the random value of arrays. So i think i need to push to another array the itens where the interaction is true. Like:

```
var valueMatch = ['1', '2', '3' ,'4'];
var randomItem = valueMatch[Math.floor(Math.random() * valueMatch.length)];
console.log("randomItem:", randomItem);
```

So, i just need to know how to interact in these objects.

With you know how to make this function simplest i'll thankful for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properties of an object can be accessed using dot notation or bracket notation. Refer MDN documentation on [Property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors).

Then you can get random item using `Math.random()` as you are currently doing.

```js
var receivedValue = '11:00:00';
var myObject = {
  '11:00:00': ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
  '12:00:00': ['5', '6', '7'],
  '13:00:00': ['8', '9', '10']
};

var selectedValue = myObject[receivedValue];

var randomItem = selectedValue[Math.floor(Math.random() * selectedValue.length)];

console.log("randomItem:", randomItem);
```

Comment: Ohhh God, it's so simply!! Thank you a lot.

Comment: You're welcome @AnaPaulaFonseca. I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try this by using [Math.ceil](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil) and [Math.random](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

```js
var reveivedValue = '11:00:00',
  randomItem = '',
  myObject = {
    '11:00:00': ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
    '12:00:00': ['5', '6', '7'],
    '13:00:00': ['8', '9', '10']
  };

var valueMatch = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];
var randomval = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (valueMatch.length)) - 1;
console.log("randomval:", randomval);
console.log("randomItem:", myObject[reveivedValue][randomval]);
```